# Manage/Update Records in ASP.NET With Redis using ServiceStack

Tags: c#, redis, servicestack

I'm coming from a SQL Server background, and experimenting with Redis in .NET using ServiceStack. I don't mean for Redis to be a full replacement for SQL Server, but I just wanted to get a basic idea of how to use it so I could see where we might make good use of it.

I'm struggling with what I think is a pretty basic issue. We have a list of items that are maintained in a couple of different data stores. For the sake of simplicity, assume the definition of the item is basic: an integer id and a string name. I'm trying to do the following:

- Store an item
- Retrieve an item if we only know its id
- Overwrite an existing item if we only know its id
- Show all the items for that specific type

And here's some of the code I've put together:

```
    public class DocumentRepositoryRedis
    {
        private static string DOCUMENT_ID_KEY_BASE = "document::id::";

        public IQueryable<Document> GetAllDocuments()
        {
            IEnumerable<Document> documentsFromRedis;
            using (var documents = new RedisClient("localhost").As<Document>())
            {
                documentsFromRedis = documents.GetAll();
            }
            return documentsFromRedis.AsQueryable();
        }

        public Document GetDocument(int id)
        {
            Document document = null;
            using (var redisDocuments = new RedisClient("localhost").As<Document>())
            {
                var documentKey = GetKeyByID(document.ID);
                if (documentKey != null)
                    document = redisDocuments.GetValue(documentKey);        
            }
            return document;
        }

        public void SaveDocument(Document document)
        {
            using (var redisDocuments = new RedisClient("localhost").As<Document>())
            {
                var documentKey = GetKeyByID(document.ID);
                redisDocuments.SetEntry(documentKey, document);
            }
        }

        private string GetKeyByID(int id)
        {
            return DOCUMENT_ID_KEY_BASE + id.ToString();
        }
    }
```

It all seems to work - except for GetAllDocuments. That's returning 0 documents, regardless of how many documents I have stored. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Note: Don't put `.As<T>` inside a using expression (its deprecated), correct code is: `using (var r = new RedisClient()){ r.As<Document>()... }`

Comment: @mythz - good catch, that turns into a big problem once you start connecting multiple clients since the object doesn't dispose and release its connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typed Redis client also gives you access to the non-typed methods - since Redis ultimately doesn't know or care about your object types. So when you use the client.SetEntry() method, it bypasses some of the typed client's features and just stores the object by a key. You'll want to use the client.Store method since it goes ahead and creates a SET in Redis with all the object IDs related to your type. This SET is important because it's what the GetAll method relies on to serve back all the objects to you. The client.Store method does infer the ID automatically so you'll want to play around with it.

You'd change your GetDocument(int id) and SaveDocument(Document document) methods to use the client.GetById(string id) method, and you'd use client.Store(T value) method. You won't need your GetKeyByID() method anymore. I believe your Document object will need an "Id" property for the typed client to infer your object ID.

Comment: Thanks, Mike. I actually have a property on Document called "ID", but it had no correlation with the keys generated by the Store method. I'd get a key like "urn:document:24110047" when the ID of a document was 1. Calling Store on the EXACT same document would not overwrite the one in Redis already - it would generate an entirely new record. Is there any way to get the Store method to use predictable keys?

Comment: I believe it has to be Id not ID. If it doesn't find Id then it just calculates a Hash on the object for an ID.

Comment: One other thing, you can also have your objects implement the interface IHasId<T>, or you can use the [PrimaryKey] attribute on whatever Id field you're using. I'm looking at the code for IdUtils @ https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/Utils/IdUtils.cs